# post file and other data to php server

Tags: android

I'm experienced with PHP, JavaScript and a lot of other scripting languages, but I don't have a lot of experience with Java or Android.
I'm using below code to send file to sever, that is run without any problem, but I want to POST other data like "operation=upload_file" with file.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

//creating new dataoutputstream
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
//writing bytes to data outputstream
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);


//returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
//selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
//setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

//reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
//loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
while (bytesRead > 0){
    //write the bytes read from inputstream
    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
}

dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

//response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
if(serverResponseCode == 200){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
        }
    });
}

//closing the input and output streams
fileInputStream.close();
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private void doFileUpload(String filePath) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";
    String urlString = BASE_URL + "upload.php";

    try {
        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        Log.i("Debug", "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }

    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String str;
        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
        }
        inStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```